# Discriminant of the ring class field of the order $\mathcal{O}=\mathbb{Z} \left[\frac{D+\sqrt{D}}{2}\right]$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, quadratic-forms, class-field-theory

Let's look at the procedure in **the main theorem** of [this MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/361082/necessary-and-sufficient-condition-for-a-prime-to-be-represented-by-an-arbitrary): $\color{Red}{\text{Starting}}$ from a discriminant $D$, and at the $\color{Green}{\text{end}}$, we $\color{Green}{\text{find}}$ a polynomial $f_{D, h}(x)$. [That procedure just tells us about the existence of the class field, and does not give us an efficient method to compute the class field, so we do not know $f_{D, h}(x)$ practically.]

1. What can we say about the discriminant of the ring class field of the order $\mathcal{O}=\mathbb{Z}\left[\frac{D+\sqrt{D}}{2}\right]$ in the imaginary quadratic field $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{D})$ comparing with $D$?

> 2. **My Question is**: I ask the first question because I am looking for something in the reverse order: $\color{Green}{\text{Starting}}$ from a polynomial $f(x)$ which is a minimal polynomial of some primitive element for some ring class field of a quadratic order, how can I $\color{Red}{\text{find}}$ a corresponding Discriminant $D$? In other words: What is the relation between discriminant of the ring class field of the order $\mathcal{O}=\mathbb{Z}\left[\frac{D+\sqrt{D}}{2}\right]$ in the imaginary quadratic field $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{D})$ and $D$?

If one can give a somehow satisfying relation for the first question, then we may have a good restriction for the choices for $D$. For instance:

3. If we let [$f(x)=x^3-x-1$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/11747/galoisian-sets-of-prime-numbers), I do not know how should I reach to $D=-4\times23$, note that $\operatorname{Disc}(x^3-x-1)=-23$.
4. If we let [$f(x)=x^3-4x-1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2846131/set-of-primes-p-for-which-x3-4x-1-factors-completely-over-gfp), I do not know how should I reach to $D=4\times229$, note that $\operatorname{Disc}(x^3-4x-1)=229$.

considering (3) and (4) would lead me to guess that discriminant of the ring class field of the order $\mathcal{O}=\mathbb{Z} \left[\frac{D + \sqrt{D}}{2}\right]$ is equal to $D$ module ${\mathbb{Q}}/{\mathbb{Q}^{\times 2}}$, and this is the reason why I asked (1) but the following prevents me from going on:

5. If we let [$f(x)=x^4-x^3-2x^2-2x-1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2887405/set-of-primes-p-which-x4-x3-2x2-2x-1-completely-factors-in-finite-field-o), I do not know how should I reach to $D=-4\times95$, note that $\operatorname{Disc}(x^4-x^3-2x^2-2x-1)=-5\times95$.

Comment: Do you get something from the [Conductor-discriminant_formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conductor-discriminant_formula)

Comment: This seems like it should possibly be split into multiple questions. What do you mean by the "discriminant of X in the field Y"? These rings you talk about are $\mathbb Z$-lattices and have a discriminant without having to think about the field in which they live.

Comment: Also, the ring you describe is not necessarily an order as in particular that generator need not be integral for certain choices of $D$, like $D=2$.

Comment: @reuns Thanks for introducing [Conductor-discriminant formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conductor-discriminant_formula), honestly I can not go further easily.

As I emphasized in my question, **my concern is the second question**: to do the reverse procedure in [this MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/361082/necessary-and-sufficient-condition-for-a-prime-to-be-represented-by-an-arbitrary) in the reverse order.

I just meant *If one can give a somehow satisfying easy relation for the first question, then we may have a good restriction for the choices for D*.

Comment: @TokenToucan (1) That ring class field is a field extension of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{D})$, so we can speak about its discriminant.
(2) In the direct procedure of [this MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/361082/necessary-and-sufficient-condition-for-a-prime-to-be-represented-by-an-arbitrary), we assumed that $D$ is a discriminant, so $\mathcal{O}=\mathbb{Z} [\frac{D+\sqrt{D}}{2}]$ is definitely an order.
(3) In the reverse procedure, when we speak about the order $\mathcal{O}=\mathbb{Z} [\frac{D+\sqrt{D}}{2}]$, we assume the Implicit condition that we are looking for a Discriminant $D$.

Comment: To me your question 1. is given an order $O$ of $O_K ,K=Q(\sqrt{D})$ and $L$ its ring class field, then (class field theory) you know the Galois group and Hecke characters of $L/K$ and the conductor discriminant formula gives $Disc(L)$. Your question 2. is given an abelian extension $F/K$ then you need to find (through class field theory) the order $O$ and (quotient of) $Cl(O)$ which corresponds to $Gal(F/K)$ through the Artin map.

Comment: @reuns I am not proficient in the subject, and **maybe I am mistaken**; **but** as far as my knowledge allows, your point about the second question just says about the **existence**, and does not give a **practical** and **effective** method to **construct** that order **explicitly**.

Answer (score 1):

A partial answer to Q($1$): If we add the assumption that "$D$ is fundamental", then the root discriminant of the Hilbert class field would be equal to the root discriminant of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{D})$. Especially in the case of the odd class numbers, the discriminant is the same as $D$ module ${\mathbb{Q}}/{\mathbb{Q}^{\times 2}}$, but this does not help us to give even a partial answer for Q($2$).

A partial answer to Q($2$): If we add the assumption that "$\deg(f)=3$", then $D=f^2\text{Disc}(f(x))$ would works for every nonzero integer $f$. Aslo, sometimes we can find smaller $D$ than $\text{Disc}(f(x))$. This would answer Q($3$) and Q($4$) immediately.